# value range for img filter brightness function in php gd

Tags: php, gd, brightness

Anyone has any idea what is the value range for IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS function in PHP GD? 
I cannot find it in manual. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [comments section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#72329):

> -255 = min brightness, 0 = no change, +255 = max brightness